# How to put ImageView in Xamarin.Android App which resizes itself depending on device screen size?

Tags: xamarin.android, imageview, resize

I have created an image with in Android Asset Studio and it gave me zip file containing folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, each folder contains the png image with different proportions. I pasted these folders in Resources/drawable folder in my android project. Then I created:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_ac_unit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

But nothing displays on screen. In google there are a lot of examples but it seems they are for android with java because when I follow them using Xamarin.Android it's not working.

Comment: Arrange drawable folders like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_3_-_alternate_resources/Images/alternate-resources-vs.png) -  [image-source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_3_-_alternate_resources/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your problem is that your ImageView's image is from the Android system, please try the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_ac_unit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

This should be corrected. As you might have noticed I changed the android:src. The value you had was :

> android:src="@android:drawable/ic_ac_unit"

And that is trying to get the drawable with the name "ic_ac_unit" from the Android OS's predefined drawables, and not from your drawables. That is the issue that I'm seeing.

Also your "drawable-resolution" folders, created by the Android Asset Studio should be pasted directly in the Resources folder of your project and not inside the Resource/drawable folder.